# Huge overhead of multiple Index JOINs over a single row

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-performance

Consider the following type of query, which has many joins:

```
select t0.*, t1.*, etc..
from t0
left join t1 on t0.t1_id = t1.id
left join t2 on t0.t2_id = t2.id
etc..
left join t11 on t0.t11_id = t11.id
where t0.id = ?
```

This query takes around 100ms to finish, which in my opinion is too much. At most this query returns a single row (because it's filtered by an id = ?) and around 60 ish columns. This is the explain analyze I'm getting from PostgreSQL (note that the table and btree index names were obfuscated):

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.65..53.82 rows=1 width=1530) (actual time=0.043..0.045 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.23..45.39 rows=1 width=1504) (actual time=0.040..0.042 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3.82..36.95 rows=1 width=1478) (actual time=0.036..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3.39..28.51 rows=1 width=833) (actual time=0.032..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.97..20.06 rows=1 width=188) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.55..19.21 rows=1 width=172) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2.26..18.90 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=0.024..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.84..18.41 rows=1 width=140) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.42..17.55 rows=1 width=124) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.13..17.24 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.71..16.75 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Index Scan using idx_0 on t0  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                              ->  Index Scan using idx_1 on t1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using idx_2 on t2   (cost=0.42..0.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_3 on t3  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            ->  Index Scan using idx_4 on t4  (cost=0.42..0.86 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_5 on t5  (cost=0.42..0.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Scan using idx_6 on t6   (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using idx_7 on t7   (cost=0.42..0.86 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_8 on t8   (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=645) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using idx_9 on t9   (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=645) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_10 on t10  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_11 on t11 (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning Time: 4.132 ms
Execution Time: 0.110 ms
```

All columns are indexed as you can see in the explain analyze, yet the query is taking too long. The Execution Time of ~100ms is away off of those 0.110 ms that were estimated. Without all those joins the query takes 5ms.

Why are the joins over a single row so slow? Is there any trick to optimize queries with multiple joins?

Comment: Why do you think 100ms is too slow? How are you measuring that runtime? If you try selecting your results to a temporary table and measured the runtime, is it significantly quicker? (If so, this would be indicative that it's not the query that's the issue, rather the render time of the results to the client.)

Comment: Err... the execution time is ~ 0.1 ms and **not** 100ms?

Comment: @J.D. The 100ms are measured after retrieving the results from Knex ‒ https://knexjs.org/. The times don't include rendering, only the print of the results, which is just a couple of bytes.

Comment: So you better investigate Knex, and how it is connected to your DB.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW those ~0.1ms are an estimation, I think. Even running the query in psql it takes ~50ms.

Comment: I still would question that the client side (knexjs in this case) is where the added time comes from. Also, I doubt you're returning only a few bytes of data when you're returning 60 columns, even for only 1 row. If every column was a 1 byte data type, that's 60 bytes in itself, unless the majority of the data points being returned are null.

Comment: The time taken is not in executing this query, it's either in getting the results to your client or for the client to render it. Do you really need to `select *` for every table you're using? There's going to be lots of columns you don't need (the ones in the joins for starters). What are the data types being used, any lobs?

Comment: @RicardoGomes: the time shown by `explain (analyze)` with `Execution Time:` is the actual time it took the server to run the statement and retrieve all rows it produces. It's **not** an estimate. Those rows are just not sent back to the client. If the execution time is 0.1ms and you measure 100ms in your frontend the  difference is either caused by network slowness (unlikely with a 1.5kb result) or by the application which can't receive and render the rows any faster. Even if you could reduce the statement from 0.1ms to 0.01ms you'd still have the 100ms overhead of your application